# How to compare a particular field to a string in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The `Cons.getpersonIdForRegisteredUser()` method returns a string.
My query has two parts: one is to check the person `id` and the other is `data enabled`

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int i, final Bundle bundle) {

    String sortOrder = ContactProviderContract.ContactDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME
                + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

    String selection = ContactProviderContract.
                ContactDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERSON_ID + " != " + Cons.getPersonIdForRegisteredUser(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                + " AND "
                + ContactProviderContract.ContactDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_ENABLED + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { "1" };

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                   ContactProviderContract.CONTACTS_URI, 
                   ContactProviderContract.ContactDatabaseEntry.MIN_DETAILS_COLUMNS,
                   selection, 
                   selectionArgs, 
                   sortOrder);
}
```

The error is that the string retrieved from the method `Cons.getpersonid...()` is considered as a column and not as a string to compare.

Comment: You can't have `!=` or `AND` with the selection. Those need to be `WHERE` arguments.

Comment: What line of code causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the error correctly, then you should place that `Cons.getPersonId...` into the `selectionArgs`.

```
String selection = ContactProviderContract.
            ContactDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PERSON_ID + " != ?" +
            + " AND "
            + ContactProviderContract.ContactDatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_ENABLED + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { "1" , Cons.getPersonIdForRegisteredUser(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) };
```